# inserting timestamp values into Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

we are inserting values to a table through a procedure , one values we are inserting is current_timestamp.
throwing below while inserting timestamp values.
`too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')] expected 1, got 2\n Stack Trace:\nundefined\n`

below is the syntax:

`var create_vol1=snowflake.execute({sqlText: "INSERT INTO CDW_DB.LOAD_timestamp VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(Current_Timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))"});`

please correct me if i am wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `current_timestamp` function already returns a timestamp so you don't need to do anything to it. Just insert it like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO CDW_DB.LOAD_timestamp VALUES (Current_Timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, i have used it but it is loading extra -000 at the end of value, i need to load in this format 'dd-mm-yyyy hh-mi-ss', that is why i am using to_timestamp.

Comment: What is the data type of the column you're inserting into? There is a difference between a timestamp and a string representation of a timestamp. Timestamp data types don't have a format.

Comment: data type is Timestamp

Comment: how would we convert to a specified format if it is having data type as Timestamp?

Comment: Have a read of this documentation about the different types of timestamps. The first step would be to understand which one you're using for that column. You may have to look up the `timestamp_type_mapping` if it's really just shown as `timestamp` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp

Comment: Thank you, will go through it.